# Can we have the profile page biography editor show the width of the actual space?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, editor

The profile page editor has a full-width preview window for the biography. However, the actual bio is much narrower and shorter. Why don't we have it so you can preview how it will look after it is posted?

If implemented, we might want to wait for the new profile page it doesn't have to be changed a second time, but I thought I'd just through this out here to suggest.